# HashMap keys and values

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have a hash map and values in it. Now i want to set the values in the map as keys and keys as values. Can anyone suggest any idea?

My Map is

```
Map<String, String> col=new HashMap<String, String>();
col.put("one","four");
col.put("two","five");
col.put("three","Six");
```

Now i want to create an another map and put it in other way as i told above. ie,

```
Map<String, String> col2=new HashMap<String, String>();
col.put("five","one");
col.put("four","two");
col.put("Six","three");
```

Anybody has idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your values are unique in your hashmap, you can do like this.

```
// Get the value collection from the old HashMap
Collection<String> valueCollection = col.values();
Iterator<String> valueIterator = valueCollection.iterator();
HashMap<String, String> col1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
while(valueIterator.hasNext()){
     String currentValue = valueIterator.next();
     // Find the value in old HashMap
     Iterator<String> keyIterator = col.keySet().iterator();
     while(keyIterator.hasNext()){
          String currentKey = keyIterator.next();
          if (col.get(currentKey).equals(currentValue)){
               // When found, put the value and key combination in new HashMap
               col1.put(currentValue, currentKey);
               break;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: -1: Unnecessary n² complexity.

Comment: @Boann I agree. `entrySet` method didn't strike to me.

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
Map<String, String> col2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : col.entrySet()) {
    col2.put(e.getValue(), e.getKey());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another `Map` and iterate through keys/values one by one and put in new `Map`. finally delete old one.